# How to get something show up in all tabs of a tab bar

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I am making a game. When this game first starts up it shows the title screen, and on this screen there is a shop button. When that button is clicked the shop scene shows up. I want this screen to have three tabs at the bottom, themes, costumes, and coins (and possible power-ups). In all of those screen I want there to a back button at the top and a label showing the amount of coins the play has. I am using a tab bar controller and I do not know how to make it so that there something shows up in all of the tabs.

Comment: you need class add in tabbar controller then showing all class

Comment: @Rohitsuvagiya I have not really used tab bar controllers before and I do not understand what you said.

Comment: Please see.... http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: Then http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/exploring-tab-bar-controller--mobile-14063

Comment: Then... http://codewithchris.com/ios-tab-bar-app/

Comment: That was very helpful, but I read through all of them it does not say anything about to have the something show up in all of the tabs